# SCSS fix for PrimeNG `pFocusTrap` bug when parent of focusable element is hidden

Tags: sass, accessibility, focus, primeng, bootstrap-5

[I found a bug in PrimeNG `pFocusTrap`](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12349).
Basically when tabbing through focusable elements, focus will get stuck on an element whose ancestor is `display:none`. Here is my fix:

```
$displays: inline inline-block block grid table table-cell table-row flex inline-flex;
$tabbable: 'a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]';

@function d-size($size) {
    $ret: ();
    @each $n in $displays {
       $ret: append($ret,'.d-'+$size+'-'+$n,'comma');
    }
    @return $ret;
}

.d-none:not(#{d-size('sm')},#{d-size('md')},#{d-size('lg')},#{d-size('xl')}) *:is(#{$tabbable}),
.d-sm-none:not(#{d-size('md')},#{d-size('lg')},#{d-size('xl')}) *:is(#{$tabbable}),
.d-md-none:not(#{d-size('lg')},#{d-size('xl')}) *:is(#{$tabbable}),
.d-lg-none:not(#{d-size('xl')}) *:is(#{$tabbable}),
.d-xl-none *:is(#{$tabbable})
{
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Basically it applies `display:none` to any tabbable descendant of any elements that are using bootstraps `d-xx-none` utility.

**My question is:** I'm pretty new to SCSS, but is there any way to refactor and optimize the lines of code, and are there any bugs I may have overlooked?

Comment: How is it possible to focus a child of a `display: none` parent? They are excluded from the tab order. Is it focussed before the parent gets hidden?

Comment: @Andy It doesn't focus the hidden element. The pFocusTrap implementation will get stuck focus on the previous tabbable element.

Comment: Can you try to [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue please? Ideally with the code snippet.

Comment: @Andy here is my bug report https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12349